# Internal server error when deploying a Mezzanine project on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, mezzanine

I am trying to deploy mezzanine project on heroku. I came across a lot of tutorials like 
http://stevenelliottjr.github.io/, and others but had no luck so far. When i try to use it on development using foreman i receive `"Internal server error"` even when i have `DEBUG=True`.

Following is my `settings.py` file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals


USE_SOUTH = True


########################
# MAIN DJANGO SETTINGS #
########################

# People who get code error notifications.
# In the format (('Full Name', 'email@example.com'),
#                ('Full Name', 'anotheremail@example.com'))
ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

TIME_ZONE = None

# If you set this to True, Django will use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en"

# Supported languages
_ = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
)

# A boolean that turns on/off debug mode. When set to ``True``, stack traces
# are displayed for error pages. Should always be set to ``False`` in
# production. Best set to ``True`` in local_settings.py
DEBUG = True

# Whether a user's session cookie expires when the Web browser is closed.
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = False

# Tuple of IP addresses, as strings, that:
#   * See debug comments, when DEBUG is true
#   * Receive x-headers
INTERNAL_IPS = ("127.0.0.1",)

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
    "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ("mezzanine.core.auth_backends.MezzanineBackend",)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# The numeric mode to set newly-uploaded files to. The value should be
# a mode you'd pass directly to os.chmod.
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644


#############
# DATABASES #
#############

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        # Add "postgresql_psycopg2", "mysql", "sqlite3" or "oracle".
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.",
        # DB name or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        "NAME": "",
        # Not used with sqlite3.
        "USER": "",
        # Not used with sqlite3.
        "PASSWORD": "",
        # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        "HOST": "",
        # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        "PORT": "",
    }
}

import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
#########
# PATHS #
#########

import os

# Full filesystem path to the project.
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Name of the directory for the project.
PROJECT_DIRNAME = PROJECT_ROOT.split(os.sep)[-1]

##################
# DJANGO         #
##################
SECRET_KEY = "mysecretkey"
NEVERCACHE_KEY = "myanothersecretkey"

###########
# LOGGING #
###########

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
}
# Every cache key will get prefixed with this value - here we set it to
# the name of the directory the project is in to try and use something
# project specific.
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = PROJECT_DIRNAME

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL + "media/"

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, *MEDIA_URL.strip("/").split("/"))

# Package/module name to import the root urlpatterns from for the project.
ROOT_URLCONF = "%s.urls" % PROJECT_DIRNAME

# Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates"
# or "C:/www/django/templates".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),)


################
# APPLICATIONS #
################

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.redirects",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.sitemaps",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "mezzanine.boot",
    "mezzanine.conf",
    "mezzanine.core",
    "mezzanine.generic",
    "mezzanine.blog",
    "mezzanine.forms",
    "mezzanine.pages",
    "mezzanine.galleries",
    "mezzanine.twitter",
    #"mezzanine.accounts",
    #"mezzanine.mobile",
    "gunicorn",
)

# List of processors used by RequestContext to populate the context.
# Each one should be a callable that takes the request object as its
# only parameter and returns a dictionary to add to the context.
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "mezzanine.conf.context_processors.settings",
    "mezzanine.pages.context_processors.page",
)

# List of middleware classes to use. Order is important; in the request phase,
# these middleware classes will be applied in the order given, and in the
# response phase the middleware will be applied in reverse order.
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.UpdateCacheMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.request.CurrentRequestMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForDeviceMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForHostMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.AdminLoginInterfaceSelectorMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.SitePermissionMiddleware",
    # Uncomment the following if using any of the SSL settings:
    # "mezzanine.core.middleware.SSLRedirectMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.pages.middleware.PageMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",
)

# Store these package names here as they may change in the future since
# at the moment we are using custom forks of them.
PACKAGE_NAME_FILEBROWSER = "filebrowser_safe"
PACKAGE_NAME_GRAPPELLI = "grappelli_safe"
GRAPPELLI_ADMIN_TITLE = "custom title"

#########################
# OPTIONAL APPLICATIONS #
#########################

# These will be added to ``INSTALLED_APPS``, only if available.
OPTIONAL_APPS = (
    "debug_toolbar",
    "django_extensions",
    "compressor",
    PACKAGE_NAME_FILEBROWSER,
    PACKAGE_NAME_GRAPPELLI,
)

###################
# DEPLOY SETTINGS #
###################

# These settings are used by the default fabfile.py provided.
# Check fabfile.py for defaults.

# FABRIC = {
#     "SSH_USER": "", # SSH username for host deploying to
#     "HOSTS": ALLOWED_HOSTS[:1], # List of hosts to deploy to (eg, first host)
#     "DOMAINS": ALLOWED_HOSTS, # Domains for public site
#     "REPO_URL": "ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/project", # Project's repo URL
#     "VIRTUALENV_HOME":  "", # Absolute remote path for virtualenvs
#     "PROJECT_NAME": "", # Unique identifier for project
#     "REQUIREMENTS_PATH": "requirements.txt", # Project's pip requirements
#     "GUNICORN_PORT": 8000, # Port gunicorn will listen on
#     "LOCALE": "en_US.UTF-8", # Should end with ".UTF-8"
#     "DB_PASS": "", # Live database password
#     "ADMIN_PASS": "", # Live admin user password
#     "SECRET_KEY": SECRET_KEY,
#     "NEVERCACHE_KEY": NEVERCACHE_KEY,
# }


##################
# LOCAL SETTINGS #
##################

# Allow any settings to be defined in local_settings.py which should be
# ignored in your version control system allowing for settings to be
# defined per machine.
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass


####################
# DYNAMIC SETTINGS #
####################

# set_dynamic_settings() will rewrite globals based on what has been
# defined so far, in order to provide some better defaults where
# applicable. We also allow this settings module to be imported
# without Mezzanine installed, as the case may be when using the
# fabfile, where setting the dynamic settings below isn't strictly
# required.
try:
    from mezzanine.utils.conf import set_dynamic_settings
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    set_dynamic_settings(globals())
```

and below is my `wsgi.py` file:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import os

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
settings_module = "%s.settings" % PROJECT_ROOT.split(os.sep)[-1]
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", settings_module)

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application()
```

and i have added the following lines to my `project's urls.py` file:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    # new code goes here
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$',
         'django.views.static.serve',
         {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

and finally my `Procfile`:

```
web: python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 1
```

also my `logs`:

```
2014-07-31T07:05:26.250872+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:28172 -w 1`
2014-07-31T07:05:26.816662+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2014-07-31T08:08:44.222150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2014-07-31T08:08:44.222364+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2014-07-31T08:08:47.016592+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-07-31T08:08:48.929108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2014-07-31T08:25:18.545548+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2014-07-31T08:25:18.545833+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2014-07-31T08:25:24.962991+00:00 app[web.1]:   warn("TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: %s" % tz)
2014-07-31T08:25:25.077055+00:00 app[web.1]: !!!         installed with your project. Ex.:
2014-07-31T08:25:25.077052+00:00 app[web.1]: !!! 
2014-07-31T08:25:24.962973+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/conf.py:59: UserWarning: TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: Etc/UTC
2014-07-31T08:25:25.077045+00:00 app[web.1]: !!!
2014-07-31T08:25:25.077050+00:00 app[web.1]: !!! WARNING: This command is deprecated.
2014-07-31T08:25:25.077053+00:00 app[web.1]: !!!         You should now run your application with the WSGI interface
2014-07-31T08:25:25.077056+00:00 app[web.1]: !!! 
2014-07-31T08:25:25.077062+00:00 app[web.1]: !!!             gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application
2014-07-31T08:25:25.077064+00:00 app[web.1]: !!! 
2014-07-31T08:25:25.077065+00:00 app[web.1]: !!!         See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/
2014-07-31T08:25:25.077067+00:00 app[web.1]: !!!         for more info.
2014-07-31T08:25:25.077070+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-31T08:25:25.077068+00:00 app[web.1]: !!!
2014-07-31T08:25:26.602059+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=adaptube-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=a3294bc9-8458-492e-ad0e-0cbcb50ffd63 fwd="122.163.238.149" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=5 status=500 bytes=541
```

Please someone tell me what is wrong with my code.

`**NOTE:**`
Even if i turn `DEBUG=True` in my `settings.py` i see "internal server error" not the detailed debug.